# How to get all counts of likes,comments and share of post of our linkedin page? [REST API IN V2 ]

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

I am trying a rest API.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/posts/{post-id}/relation-to-viewer/is-liked
```

It gives me an error like:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource posts does not exist",
    "status": 404
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you could use the [Retrieve Social Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-social-actions) endpoint

Comment: I tried "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/" API. but still, it's giving me the same error                                                                                                                         
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource socialActions does not exist",
    "status": 404
}